# Get Images of a listview from another process in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get all the images from listview which I am running from another process.

I am trying ::SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_GETIMAGELIST, LVSIL_NORMAL) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-getimagelist says it returns a handle but I am not getting any information

I want to get all the images of the listview item in the form of bitmap or any other form.

Any sample code would be helpful

Comment: What is the call returning? Is it a value or null? Is null what you mean by, *I am not getting any information*?

Comment: Its returning a null value

Comment: I'm coming up with nothing on sharing an image handle between apps. Is the other process yours? google `cross process handle sharing`. It doesn't look like you can just share a handle without some hoops. But I don't know for sure. You should add more tags that address this to your question.